# C# BinaryTree, BinarySearchTree and BinaryHeap

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-heap

For my exam next week I've to learn how to build a BinaryTree, BinarySearchTree and  BinaryHeap. The only problem is, the most examples on the web are not simple enough to understand. They are just a bunch of code without documentation. I am looking for an easy example to build the three datastructures. Think about an example with some documentation for the functions. How everything works. Does anybody know some good tutorials for the three datastructures or have a good example for me?

Comment: I think the better test is whether you can use a search engine to answer your own question....no one can 'give' you understanding; it's something you have to work at.

Comment: Just what I say, the ones I found where not simple enough, so maybe someone else knows some simple ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to see in pseudocode how can be use this data structures. The C# is a similar to Java, so you can easily see some tutorial about this data structures in Java. Some similar questions is [Binary Search Tree in C# Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366402/binary-search-tree-in-c-sharp-implementation) and [Is there a built-in Binary Search Tree in .NET 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262947/is-there-a-built-in-binary-search-tree-in-net-4-0). Some tutorial is [A Quick and Dirty Binary Search Tree in C#](http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/a-quick-and-dirty-binary-search-tree-in-c/), [Binary Search Trees (BSTs) in C#](http://snipd.net/binary-search-trees-bsts-in-c), [Binary Search Tree implemented in C#](http://pli5.blogspot.ro/2012/08/binary-search-tree-implemented-in-c.html) and [BST (Binary Search Tree)](http://seedotnet.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/bst-binary-search-tree/)  and [C# Binary Search Tree](http://www.vcskicks.com/binary-search-tree.php).

Comment: You mean I can use tutorials of the java side of the trees and heap as well? They work exactly the same but only the language is different?

Comment: @P Griep I mean that you try to put the algorithms in pseudocode, and the language that is closest to the syntax of C# is Java.

Answer (score 1):

Try this links
Its a whole tutorial on the topic
refer to lecture 26 and 25.

It wont give you the code but a good understanding of the concept

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_3BM0ykITM

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_3BM0ykITM

Comment: Thank you, understanding the concept is always a good way. Maybe I can learn some more of the concept with this instead of our 2 paged school documents.